# Outlet Relocation and wiring

Tags: wiring

I have an outlet I am going to move up the wall.  The outlet has two cables running to it.  My question is, if I run a new straight down from my new outlet location, do I just tie together all three cables together at bottom, cap them, same color, and wire up the new outlet at top with the other end of the new cable?

I will be putting a blank face plate at the bottom where the tie in will be per code so it is accessible.  Please let me know if this is correct, I have some electrical knowledge just have not done this before and want to make sure it is acceptable.

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Update:

The tabs appear to be intact, so am I safe to assume if I wire this up like I spoke of I will be ok? [image][image]

Comment: Harper makes a good point. Why _move_ the outlet when you can just add a new one? Use pigtails to connect the existing outlet (since you'll have too many wires to use just the screws).

Comment: I would not have too many wires to use just the screws.  The bottom outlet would be gone completely, and just have the two existing cables, along with the new cable, capped together by color, the new outlet would be higher up the wall and the other cable end just connected to this.

Comment: You would _if you retained the existing outlet_, which was my point.

Comment: No I understand that, I just wanted to do away with the outlet all together, just wanting a clean look at the bottom, as I am mounting a TV up.  I know they have the in wall plug systems but I dont like how it looks.

Answer (score 2):

Your plan sounds good, except for one thing you do have to check.

Anytime you remove an outlet, make sure you are not falling below the minimum outlets required.   In particular, a 6-foot cord from an appliance anywhere along the wall needs to be able to reach a power outlet.  It appears your old outlet is near a threshold, so if it's moving farther from the threshold, that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan is correct. Unless you have a switched outlet or some other oddity, it's just black-to-black, white-to-white, and ground-to-ground across the board.

<sub>FYI, "Romex™" is a brand name that's like "Kleenex™". It's not an industry term for "building wire" and doesn't translate well to other countries. Also, the company makes *many* products. Just "cable" usually suffices in house wiring discussions.</sub>

Comment: Sorry for the Romex reference, I do know it is just a brand name, I normally would have just said cable but I guess I was just trying to reference it better lol –

Comment: For future reference, the technical generic name for it is NM cable (for Non-Metallic), and that is the name used in code.

Answer (score -1):

Looking closely at the pictures of the sides of your outlet, I'd say **NO**. It looks like the tabs have been broken off so that each plug of the outlet has a separate supply of power. Is one outlet switched while the other is always on?

I'd suggest running two new cables down from the new location to the old and tying one new black/white to one set of black/white in the old box, the other new black/white to the other old black white, and tying all the grounds together (as the two grounds appear to be grouped now.

In the new box, either reusing the old outlet or breaking the tab off of a new outlet, wire it up the same, with one of the new wire's black/white to one pair of screws and the other new wire to the other pair of screws. Make sure, of course, to tie the grounds together and ground the switch.

Of course, if you're looking to remove the switched control of one of the plugs or have both of them switched, then tie one new cable to the appropriate white/black pair in the old box and run that up the wall to the new location and do *not* break the tab off of a new outlet. Make sure you cap the unused wires in the old box.

Comment: It's more likely that they used the second screw as a daisy chain point. Not allowed for the neutral though. It's something to check.

Comment: Not to familiar with what you mean by tabs been broken off?  All I do know is that both the outlets work at same time if I plug something into them, there is no switch that turns on one plug on only.

Comment: @Tom on a standard outlet like the one you have, there is a small brass tab between the metal backing plates behind the screws. This allows you to attach power to one set of screws and get power out of both outlets. The tab is also designed to be broken off so that you can provide separate power (usually switched to one and unswitched to the other). If you look closely at the side of the outlet, you should be able to see the tab. If you only see black plastic between the screws, then the tab has been removed. If you're not sure, post a closeup pic of the side of the outlet.

Comment: Since I seem to be the only one who thinks they're missing, they may actually be there, but, to me, when I zoom in on your pics, it looks like they've been removed.